# MySQL ROW_COUNT after REPLACE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting some odd values for `ROW_COUNT` after a `REPLACE`. In the example below, the second REPLACE returns 2 not 1. Can anyone explain why? This happens on both MySQL 5.6 and 5.7

```
create table test(
    id int not null primary key, 
    d  int not null unique
);

replace into test(id,d) values(1,1);
select row_count(); -- returns 1

replace into test(id,d) values(1,1);
select row_count(); -- returns 2... why?
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the behavior [is very well documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count):

> For `REPLACE` statements, the affected-rows value is 2 if the new row
>   replaced an old row, because in this case, one row was inserted after
>   the duplicate was deleted.

Comment: But if I remove the UNIQUE index, leaving the PRIMARY KEY I get 1

Comment: I guess it returns 1 if the new row is identical to old row (`replace ... (1, 9999)` gives 2 as expected).